# How to find a substring and delete it as well as everything that comes after it

Tags: t-sql

I've been searching for a way to update some columns of a certain table.

This update would **try** to find a certain substring and to delete it as well as every other characters that comes after it.

It's easy to delete everyhting after a certain character but I can't find a way to do the same thing with a substring.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should look at the LIKE keyword for matching strings in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that:

- the column to update is called `haystack`
- the substring to search for is called `@needle`

Here's the expression you're looking for:

```
case
 when charindex(@needle, haystack) = 0 then @haystack
 else substring(haystack, 1, charindex(@needle, haystack) - 1)
end
```

Here's an online test of the two cases (match/no match): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21209

Comment: Thank you this help very much i just needed to tune it up a little and it work perfectly. My final code is shown below

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    @substring varchar(32) = 'anySubString'
UPDATE
    myTable
SET
    colomnName = 
        (CASE WHEN charindex(@substring, colomnName) = 0 THEN
            colomnName
        ELSE
            substring(colomnName , 1, charindex(@substring, colomnName) - 1)
        END)
END
```